# CentOS 7 changes my pc time +4 hours when I boot my windows disk

Tags: linux, windows, time

On my home pc I have two disks,  one disk has windows10 installed, the other disk has CentOS 7.9 installed.

It is an Asrock motherboard and has a boot gui that lets me choose which disk to boot, and I go back and forth between windows and linux as I need to.

When I run CentOS and time is correct, I reboot and go into windows and my time is +4 hours ahead... such that it is UTC time.   { I am located in Northeast US, with DST we are UTC - 4 }
In Windows I click sync time and it corrects, but I have to do that manually every time after I use my CentOS linux disk.

How can I correct this?  What is the best way to correct this such that the local time shown in both windows and linux is correct?  *I suspect CentOS is setting my bios clock to UTC time?*

Comment: https://gadgetgang.com/dualbooting-how-to-synchronize-your-pc-clock-on-windows-and-linux/

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, that's a somewhat amusing article. It marks the "make Windows use UTC" solution as "unrecommended" in the heading, but doesn't bother to give any _reason_ for that. Except later in the other section, but then it's still just that 15+ year old Raymond Chan blog which basically boils down to "it's always been like that, and Microsoft doesn't want to change things"... (plus some defences that honestly seem rather made up.) The only reasonable argument there is the one about using scheduled startup.

Answer (score 4):

Windows likes to keep the hardware clock in local time by default, while Linux systems prefer to keep it in UTC. Keeping the clock in UTC is better, in that it allows easier daylight savings transitions without keeping track of *which* local time the HW clock is in now.

Luckily, it looks like Windows could be configured to UTC too. The registry entry that controls it appears to be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal`, which should be set to `1`. (If it doesn't exist, create it first. It should be a QWORD on a 64-bit system, and a DWORD on a 32-bit system.)

I didn't test this, but it's suggested in a few places:

- [Does Windows 10 support UTC as BIOS time?](https://superuser.com/q/975717/600133) on superuser.com
- [Gentoo Wiki: System Time / Dual booting with Windows](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/System_time#Dual_booting_with_Windows)
- [Arch Linux wiki: System Time / UTC in Microsoft Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_time#UTC_in_Microsoft_Windows)

---

The other option of course is to configure Linux to assume the hardware clock is in the local time. [With systemd, the command to use seems to be `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html). But note that systemd doesn't really like it, `timedatectl` warns:

> Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
> This mode cannot be fully supported. It will create various problems
> with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
> time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
> If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
> 'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.

If `/etc/adjtime` exists, the setting is stored there (the third line) for use by the [`hwclock` utility](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hwclock.8.html). Systemd updates the file if it exists, but I'm not sure where it stores the setting if the file doesn't exists.

I didn't test this either, and what with the issues with DST, I'd probably try to avoid it.